# Can we get the signature or arguments of a celery task on `task_prerun`

Tags: python, logging, celery, celery-task, python-logging

My plan is to log all celery task requests with the arguments they receive s I'm using the following

```
@task_prerun.connect()
def log_celery_args(task, **kwargs):
    logger.info(f"{task.name} {kwargs['kwargs']}", extra=kwargs['kwargs'])
```

The problem is this solution doesn't work when the functions don't use named parameters.
I can get the values from the `kwargs['args']` but I'd like to still have in the extras the format
`{arg_name: value}`

So my idea was if there's a way to get the signature of a task or any other way to actually get the parameters needed ?

I already tried the following :

- Tried to print all the args of `task` and `task.request` to see if I can find it there
- Saw a `signature` function but this one is actually to change it
- Tried to play around `celery.app.trace` to see if I can get it to log with the parameters

Comment: A running minimal example would help us help you.

Comment: This blog post seems to have relevant information for you: https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/11/06/celery-task-logger-format/

Comment: Yepp already saw this doc, what I needed is something generic without modifying all my celery tasks. I can already get the params, I just need in case the function is not using named parameters to get the signature of the function to map the parameters and their value in my task_prerun function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Python 3.8 onwards you can use `f"{kwargs=}"` to print all keyword arguments.

If positional arguments need to be allowed and logged then the function definition must be adapted as follows:

```py
@task_prerun.connect()
def log_celery_task_call(task, *args, **kwargs):
    logger.info(f"{task.name} {args=} {kwargs=}")
```

`*args` in the function definition will catch all positional arguments and `**kwargs` all keyword arguments. If there are no positional arguments the `args` variable will be an empty list and if no keyword arguments are supplied `kwargs` will be an empty dictionary.

See also the Python documentation for [function](https://docs.python.org/3.11/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) definitions and [calls](https://docs.python.org/3.11/reference/expressions.html#calls).

Comment: Yes I know about this, this is why I needed to get the signature of the function. In case I'm using args, the logs won't be descriptive. Mostly I would want to put them with the attribute name in the `extras`

Comment: I fail to understand exactly what it is you want - or why. But if the function signatures are what you need you can find them with introspection. See https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature

Comment: The signature function is perfect! I actually wanted to log all celery tasks in this form `logger.info(f"{task.name}", extras: {param1: value1, param2: value2})` without making changes to all the celery tasks.

Comment: I am happy this helped and you have a solution that works for you now.